# Another mass site scraper

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

I decided to look up my username for kicks, and found [this](http://www.secqa.com/index.php?qa=user&qa_1=Carcigenicate&qa_2=activity).

They seems to be scraping SO for questions with a security tag. Those questions listed appear to be every "security" related post I've been involved with on SO.

Last time I reported a similar site, it was well recieved, so it seems this is an appropriate channel to report though.

Comment: Thanks. Reported through the form.